# Feature importance using SVM's coef_ function

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am working on a text classification project and trying to use SVC(kernel= 'linear') to get the feature importance. Here is my code:
(I changed the code from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41592661/determining-the-most-contributing-features-for-svm-classifier-in-sklearn))

```
X = df1[features]
y = df1['label']


# Create selector class for text and numbers
class TextSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """Transformer to select a single column from the data frame to perform additional transformations on"""
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.key]

class NumberSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """For data grouped by feature, select subset of data at a provided key."""
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[[self.key]]

scaler = StandardScaler()    
text = Pipeline([
                ('selector', TextSelector(key='title_mainText')),
                ('vect', TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))),                
            ])

upper_title =  Pipeline([
                ('selector', NumberSelector(key='upper_title')),
                ('standard', scaler),
            ])

upper_mainText =  Pipeline([
                ('selector', NumberSelector(key='upper_mainText')),
                ('standard', scaler),
            ])

punct_title =  Pipeline([
                ('selector', NumberSelector(key='punct_title')),
                ('standard', scaler),
            ])

punct_mainText =  Pipeline([
                ('selector', NumberSelector(key='punct_mainText')),
                ('standard', scaler),
            ])


exclamations_title =  Pipeline([
                ('selector', NumberSelector(key='exclamations_title')),
                ('standard', scaler),
            ])


exclamations_text =  Pipeline([
                ('selector', NumberSelector(key='exclamations_text')),
                ('standard', scaler),
            ])


feats = FeatureUnion([('title_mainText', text), 
                      ('upper_title', upper_title),
                      ('upper_mainText', upper_mainText),
                      ('punct_title', punct_title),
                      ('punct_mainText', punct_mainText),                    
                      ('exclamations_text', exclamations_text),
                      ('exclamations_title', exclamations_title),                        

feature_processing = Pipeline([('feats', feats)])

pipeline = Pipeline([
        ('features', feats),
        ('classifier', SVC(C=1, kernel= 'linear', max_iter= 1000, tol=0.0001, probability=True))
    ])


    def f_importances(coef, names):
        imp = coef
        imp,names = zip(*sorted(zip(imp,names)))
        plt.barh(range(len(names)), imp, align='center')
        plt.yticks(range(len(names)), names)
        plt.show()

    features_names = ['title_mainText', 'upper_title', 'upper_mainText', 'punct_title', 'punct_mainText',
                      'exclamations_title', 'exclamations_text']
    pipeline.fit(X, y)
    clf = pipeline.named_steps['classifier']
    f_importances(clf.coef_, features_names)
```

However, it shows an error message, and I don't know where I have done wrong.
Did someone have the experience with this before?

> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>        13 pipeline.fit(X, y)
>        14 clf = pipeline.named_steps['classifier']
>   ---> 15 f_importances((clf.coef_[0]), features_names)
>        16
>
> in f_importances(coef, names)
>         5     imp = coef
>         6     imp,names = zip(*sorted(zip(imp,names)))
>   ----> 7     plt.barh(range(len(names)), imp, align='center')
>         8     plt.yticks(range(len(names)), names)
>         9     plt.show()
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py in
>   barh(*args, **kwargs)    2667                       mplDeprecation)
>   2668     try:
>   -> 2669         ret = ax.barh(*args, **kwargs)    2670     finally:    2671         ax._hold = washold
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in
>   barh(self, *args, **kwargs)    2281
>   kwargs.setdefault('orientation', 'horizontal')    2282         patches
>   = self.bar(x=left, height=height, width=width,
>   -> 2283                            bottom=y, **kwargs)    2284         return patches    2285
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py in
>   inner(ax, *args, **kwargs)    1715
>   warnings.warn(msg % (label_namer, func.**name**),    1716
>   RuntimeWarning, stacklevel=2)
>   -> 1717             return func(ax, *args, **kwargs)    1718         pre_doc = inner.**doc**    1719         if pre_doc is None:
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py in
>   bar(self, *args, **kwargs)    2091             elif orientation ==
>   'horizontal':    2092                 r.sticky_edges.x.append(l)
>   -> 2093             self.add_patch(r)    2094             patches.append(r)    2095
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in
>   add_patch(self, p)    1852         if p.get_clip_path() is None:
>   1853             p.set_clip_path(self.patch)
>   -> 1854         self._update_patch_limits(p)    1855         self.patches.append(p)    1856         p._remove_method = lambda h:
>   self.patches.remove(h)
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py in
>   _update_patch_limits(self, patch)    1868         # or height.    1869         if (isinstance(patch, mpatches.Rectangle) and
>   -> 1870                 ((not patch.get_width()) and (not patch.get_height()))):    1871             return    1872
>   vertices = patch.get_path().vertices
>
> /anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/base.py in
>   **bool**(self)
>       286             return self.nnz != 0
>       287         else:
>   --> 288             raise ValueError("The truth value of an array with more than one "
>       289                              "element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().")
>       290     **nonzero** = **bool**
>
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all().

Thank you!

Comment: Please post all of your code

Comment: It would help if you would edit your post to include the full traceback of the error

Comment: BTW, I was able to make your code work on a toy binary classification dataset but I had to pass in `clf.coef_[0]`, because `coef_` returns a nested array. That may be one thing tripping you up.

Comment: @JerryM. Hi, I have updated my full code now :)

Comment: @G.Anderson thank you! I tried to use  ` clf.coef_[0] ` but it shows the same error. Also i updated the full traceback of error. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scikit-Learn's documentation [states](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) that the coef_ attribute is an array of shape shape = [n_class * (n_class-1) / 2, n_features]. Assuming 4 classes and 9 features, _coef is of shape 6 x 9 (six rows and nine columns). barh on the other hand expects one value for each feature instead of six, hence you are getting an error. You can eliminate it if you sum the coefficients along each column as in the example below.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f_importances(coef, names):
    imp = coef
    imp,names = zip(*sorted(zip(imp,names)))
    plt.barh(range(len(names)), imp, align='center')
    plt.yticks(range(len(names)), names)
    plt.show()

features_names = ['title_mainText', 'upper_title', 'upper_mainText', 'punct_title', 'punct_mainText',
                  'exclamations_title', 'exclamations_text', 'title_words_not_stopword', 'text_words_not_stopword']

n_classes = 4
n_features = len(features_names)

clf_coef_ = np.random.randint(1, 30, size=(int(0.5*n_classes*(n_classes-1)), n_features))

f_importances(clf_coef_.sum(axis=0), features_names)
```

[image]